# Trouble Calculating Averages on tableau

Tags: tableau-api

Have this data set and when I am trying to plug into tableau to and calculates averages by either Day of Week or weekday/weekend, it always calculates the averages at the hourly level. Please help!

Thanks:)

[Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAlNU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use datetrunc('day',[timestamp]) to reduce your date field to just date, and not date_time. Then average.